# Can someone tell me if this is acceptable returning generic type T and undefined?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Is it ok to return generic like: T | undefined?

```typescript
type PartialSingleParam<T> = (param?: T) => T | undefined;

export const getId:PartialSingleParam<string> = href => href?.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

export const getNumber:PartialSingleParam<number> = data => data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't judge what's "acceptable" and what is not.

Typescript is just there to ensure, at compile time, that the parameter passed between functions/objects are what's expected.

If you tell Typescript that your function expects an input of generic type, and will return a thing that's either undefined or type generic then typescript will check to make sure that is the case.

---

On a side note, looking at your example, I might think that it's a little too explicit. You could just do:

```
export const getId = (href?: string) => href?.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
export const getNumber = (data?: number) => data
```

But that's personal preference and explicitly declaring return type has its benefits too. So up to you.